# How to POST an updated config.xml using Jenkins REST API?

Tags: rest, jenkins, hudson

I wanna write a groovy script to bulk update my job configuration using Jenkins REST API. But I am quite confused by its API doc (http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/my_job_name/api/).

> Fetch/Update config.xml
>
> > To programmatically obtain config.xml, hit this URL. You can also POST an updated config.xml to the same URL[http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/my_job_name/config.xml] to programmatically update the configuration of a job.

How am I gonna POST an xml file to an url mentioned above?

Answer (score 5):

The below curl command works for me.

```
curl --user $USER:$API_TOKEN -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/test/config.xml -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' --data-binary "@mymodifiedlocalconfig.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' http://<ip>/job/<job name>/config.xml --user uname:upass --data-binary @./test.xml
```

Many answers set **Content-Type: application/xml**, and it didn't work in my Jenkins. I try to set **Content-Type: application/octet-stream** and it work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I tried cURL and it worked.

```
curl -F "file=@updated_config.xml" "http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/my_job_name/config.xml"
```

Note: U will need to toggle off "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" in Jenkins config.